# Java Compilation Error- Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to int

Tags: java, compiler-errors

The question is Meadowdale Dairy Farm sells organic brown eggs to local customers. It charges $3.25 for a dozen eggs, or 45 cents for individual eggs that are not part of a dozen. Write a program that prompts a user for the number of eggs in the order and then display the amount owed with a full explanation. For example, typical output might be, You ordered 27 eggs. That’s 2 dozen at $3.25 per dozen and 3 loose eggs at 45 cents each for a total of $7.85. Save the program as EggsTwo.java.

This is what I have:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class EggsTwo
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int eggs, dozen, individual;
        double price;
        final double priceOfDozen = 3.25;
        final double priceOfIndividual = 0.45;

        eggs = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter the number of eggs in the order.", "Eggs 
        Dialog 1", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        dozen = eggs / 12; 
        individual = eggs % 12;
        price = (dozen * priceOfDozen) + (individual * priceOfIndividual);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You ordered " + eggs + " eggs. That's " + dozen + " 
        dozen and " + individual + " loose eggs at 45 cents each for a total of $" + price + ".");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: `Eggs.java` should contain `public class Eggs`; where did `EggsTwo` come from? Also, what is the problem with what you have? Does the output differ from your expectations? How so?

Comment: I weep every time a teacher gives their students a Java exercise in which amounts of money are stored in `double` variables.

Comment: I had to create a program using Scanner and JOptionPane. That's why I named it EggsTwo. It gave me the error "Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to int" but @maio290 helped me solve my problem.

Comment: @DawoodsaysreinstateMonica The teacher described the amounts of money correctly, only the implementation in the given example is bad. This is enough to make you weep.

Comment: This is not a 'GUI error'. It is a compilation error.

Comment: I understand that the name of the class has to match the name of the file. They both match. I have two programs for this question because one was supposed to use Scanner and the other was supposed to use JOptionPane. The one using scanner is named Eggs and the other one using JOptionPane is named EggsTwo. @DawoodsaysreinstateMonica

Comment: OK, sorry, I guess I misread the question.

Answer (score 1):

The method `showInputDialog` actually returns a `String`, that's why you're getting the error, which is rather clear.

```
eggs = Integer.valueOf(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter the number of eggs in the order.", "Eggs 
        Dialog 1", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE));
```

You have to convert it to a Integer first.

Answer (score 1):

the  JOptionPane.showInputDialog method returns a String. You need to parser the return to Integer like this:

String eggsValueString = JOption...
eggs = Integer.parseInt(eggsValeuString);